# Pre-Calculated Objects in Python

Tags: python, optimization

Is there a way to pre-calculate an object in Python?

Like when you use a constructor just like:

```
master = Tk()
```

Is there a way to pre-calculate and save the object and read it on startup instead of creating it?

My mind is all about saving work, or doing it in advance for the CPU. Oh and if you know a scenario where this is actually done i'd love to hear about it.

Comment: You mean something like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)? Not sure if I've understood correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to serialize an object. In Python 2 there is `pickle` and `cPickle`, which is the same but faster, but iirc Python 3 only has `pickle` (which, under the hood, is equivalent to `cPickle` from Python 2). This would allow you to save an object with its pre-calculated attributes.

```
import cPickle as pickle
import time

class some_object(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_val = sum([x**2 for x in xrange(1000000)])

start = time.time()

obj = some_object()

print "Calculated value = {}".format(obj.my_val)
with open('saved_object.pickle', 'w') as outfile: #Save the object
    pickle.dump(obj, outfile)

interim = time.time()

reload_obj = pickle.load(open('saved_object.pickle','r'))

print "Precalculated value = {}".format(reload_obj.my_val)

end = time.time()

print "Creating object took {}".format(interim - start)
print "Reloading object took {}".format(end - interim)
```

Comment: Wow, yes, this is absolutely what i was looking for. I thought about generating Windows and Buttons within and stuff and then save them to a File so i only habe to throw them on the Stack when running my Program instead of calculating every time.

Comment: Guess all i had to know was its called serializing to find this on Google, shame on me